# Getting the ServletContext

Tags: spring

I wonder as calling a bean in Spring MVC web. I tried to call this class but i do not know how to pass the ServletContext. This is the code.

```
WebApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext (sc);
Servicio servicioB= (Servicio) ctx.getBean("servB",Servicio.class);
```

How do I get the ServletContext?.

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps -

1. Autowire ServletContext object

   `@Autowired
       ServletContext context;`
2. get ServletContext object in controller class

   `private ServletContext context;`

   `public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
        this.context = servletContext;
   }`

Note : You must have implement `ServletContextAware` interface in controller class.

Comment: There is no way how to do it from the controller without using annotations, I'm starting with Spring.
<bean id = "servb" class = "com.paquetes.beanxml.clases.Servicio">
     </ bean>
I have seen examples that use Servlets for the ServletContext with the method getServletContext ()

Comment: An easier way of doing this is using the annotation Qualifier example: public class IndexController {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("servB")
    private Servicio servicio;
    System.out.printl(""+Servicio.getMensaje());
}